# install snaps without root?

Tags: ubuntu-one, root, snap

Why do we need an ubuntuone account to install snaps without root?

Are settings from the applications (or something else) saved at the ubuntuone account?

Thanks

For example without login, I can only install snaps with root:
`$ snap install hello
error: access denied (try with sudo)`

Login with Ubuntuone account:

`$ sudo snap login ***@***
Password of "***@***": 
Login successful`

After that, it is possible without root:

`$ snap install hello
hello 2.10 from 'canonical' installed`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use sudo to install the snap package and to install any snap application. The sudo command need grant permission. No need to be root and no need to have UbuntuOne to install snap or snap app.

Comment: Sorry, I added an example, maybe it was not explicit enough?

Answer (score 2):

There's a huge related discussion at https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/run-snap-without-installing-it/1764/33.

> This is not a big change, it’s just a change that is not critical today. There are way more critical things we are working on. This is something you care about but you must understand that we don’t always have exactly the same plans as every person using the software we make.

And a bug report at launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1711847

> There are many details that would be required to make this work. I won't go into this unless there's a developer committed to work with the core team to design and implement the feature. Please don't see this as a "wont fix", it's just a statement that we're not working on this at the moment.